# Parameterizing an $n$-sphere

Tags: coordinate-systems, geometry, volume

Consider an $n$-sphere embedded in $n+1$ Euclidean space. What is the parameterization of that surface expressed as a Euclidean vector $\{x_1,x_2...x_n\}$. It seems like it should be

$x_1=\sin\theta_1...\sin\theta_{n-3}\sin\theta_{n-2}\sin\theta_{n-1}$

$x_2=\sin\theta_1...\sin\theta_{n-3}\sin\theta_{n-2}\cos\theta_{n-1}$

$x_3=\sin\theta_1...\sin\theta_{n-3}\cos\theta_{n-2}$

...

$x_n=\cos\theta_1$

But I have no idea how to prove this. Does anyone have any tips? My ultimate goal is to exploit it to create a general rotation operator for a quantum circuit.

Comment: Did you compute $x_1^2+...+x_n^2$?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).

Comment: "The parametrization" is not a thing. There are uncountably many parametrizations, and this happens to be one of them. What do you need in your parametrization? I.e. what conditions does it have to satisfy to work for your needs?